# Error installing Rails using rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-3, osx-elcapitan

I use **rbenv** for installing Ruby-on-rails,i used `gem install rails` command, it seems it installs many dependencies without any problem but suddenly this error pops out:

> ERROR:  Error installing rails:
>       invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in /Users/pouyankhodabakhsh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/loofah-2.0.3.gem

I could not find anything useful to deal with the error and have no idea why this is happening.Have somebody else got any similar errors? How did you fix it and how could i do so?

I already installed Ruby 2.2.3 using ruby-build.I use a mac with El Capitan, Also i have the same problem trying to install **bundler** but i didn't have any errors during the installation of **nokogiri**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get an `undefined method 'size' for nil:NilClass` error during running `bundle install` then a cached version of a gem is corrupt. Delete that cached version of that gem that causes the error (`~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/loofah-2.0.3.gem` in your case) and run `bundle install` again.